# Advances in retail modelling

Tags: finance-mathematics, soft-question, modelling, banking

The risk-neutral modelling framework leads to very advanced and mathematically rich approach to contingent claims modelling. However, in my experience, retail modelling in Banks is done using generic econometric and AI/ML models. By retail modelling I mean in particular the credit risk models (deposits, cards, loans) and also the decision models (underwriting). All of it lacks the mathematical richness and the economic incisiveness of the no-arbitrage/risk-neutral framework. I have not found even academic attention given to this space.

Is this area of finance condemned to off-the-shelf lack of imagination data science modelling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big different between the **financial intermediation** (that can use a risk-neutral approach to prevent too large misalignment of valuations that would be due to disparities of risk aversions), and the **connection between the "real economy"** (economic and business risk on people who make deposits, get loans and reimburse them --or not--) **and the financial risk**.

The natural approach would be to propagate the same "real risk" to the financial system until it reaches another "external agent" (I mean: external to the network of financial intermediaries).

Start by figuring out who (outside of the financial system) would have **the exact opposite risk than people making deposits**?
Typically transforming deposits in loans is the step "**maturity transformation**" of a "Banking 101" course. If you have a look at Bologna, Pierluigi. [Banks’ maturity transformation: risk, reward, and policy](https://www.elibrary.imf.org/view/journals/001/2018/045/article-A001-en.xml) (International Monetary Fund, 2018), you will see that there is a rich literature on the topic. If you would have natural buyers of this risk, you could start to write a risk-neutral view on maturity transformation. The paradoxal aspect is that the user of loans are for a large part the same people who are making the deposits.

On the one hand you make a deposit, on the other hand someone else (or even yourself), get a loan. And of course: conditionally to the fact you want you money back, you (or someone else) will have difficulties to pay the interests of your (or her) loan...
There is a closed loop there, and if you want to have a mathematical glance, you should have a look at **Mean Field Games**. It is the beginning of this family of models that can endogenize stochastic control performed by a crowd of agents (see [Cardaliaguet, Pierre. Notes on mean field games. Technical report, 2010](http://www.science.unitn.it/%7Ebagagiol/NotesByCardaliaguet.pdf) for a gentle introduction).

Stochastic control is standard the way to manage decision taking in a risk-neutral environment, hence if you want to **consider liquidity** (or **crowding effects**), MFG is your theory.

For details on financial intermediation that is meant to be an introduction for future MFG users, you can have a look at [Financial markets in practice, by L and Raboun 2022](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/12731).

Last but not least **alternative data** can help to model retail behaviour, or at least to observe the outcome of these Mean Field Games, see part III of [Machine Learning and Data Sciences for Financial Markets - A Guide to Contemporary Practices](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/machine-learning-and-data-sciences-for-financial-markets/8BB31611662A96D0AB93A8A26E2D0D0A), Edited by Capponi and L (2023).